# C++: Program converting postfix to evaluation

Tags: c++

How can I convert the char in the array into an integer?

Ignore lines 5-100 it is just my stack. 
http://ideone.com/KQytD

Scroll down output #2 worked properly but output #3 did not. Some how when I pushed the value back into the stack and when I popped it it had the +'43' because of the ASCII and I cannot seem to get it into a regular integer value so I can do these operations easily.

line 116 puts input into char postfix. NOTE: input must be in postfix notation line 117 puts the single integer value into final after it has run through the function.

convertPostfixToEvaluation works as such: I scroll through each index of postfix until I read in '=' then I output the total/sum. The first if statement pushed the operands (0-9) into a stack. The second if statement if it reads in an operator then it attempts to do the operation as such in lines 134-158. After the if statements I increase the index value by 1 so it can scan the entire array.

The issue lies within the switch where I try adding,subtracting,multiply, or dividing more than 3 operands. so the 3rd one i believe is still has the value (+43 because of the ASCII).

My outputs(on the bottom of my program) show what the awkwardness is.

The cut to the chase issue. Issue converting char to int the second time around.

Comment: +1 kudos for actually trying; you have things to learn still! I'm not sure whether you use IdeOne and CodePad for SO, or you actually don't have a compiler installed? I suggest you go install one (VC++ Express or GNU C++ compilers are free, for example). Also, a redesign is in order. You want to parse numbers to ints before pushing operands onto a `StackType<int>`. Characters are _not_ your operands, so don't push them. Software is going to be inexorably **hard** unless you make your classes _model your problem_

Answer (score 0):

There are many things very likely *wrong* with this code.

---

Look up the function `isdigit`.  This should eliminate the huge `if` statement.

You may want to use a string lookup instead of the other complex `if` statement:

```
const std::string my_operators = "+-/*";

if (my_operators.find(postfix[i]) != std::string::npos)
{
    // Enter here if the character is a valid symbol.
}
```

If you "parse" character by character, you will have to build your number:

```
int number = 0;

// After detecting the character is a number:
number = number * 10 + (postfix[i] - '0');
```

The expression "postfix[i] - '0'" will return the distance between the number character and the character for zero.  The C and C++ languages guarantee the following relationship:

```
'0' < '1' < '2' < '3' < '4' < '5' < '6' < '7' < '8' < '9'
```

The languages also state that those numbers are contiguous.

Suggestion:  use `std::string` instead of an array of characters.  The `std::string` contains some helpful functions for searching, skipping characters, and obtaining a substring.

Comment: could you explain what "std::string::npos" is doing. I did my_operators.find(postfix[i]) != my_operators.npos and it does pick out the operators but I don't see how it did that. I checked npc on cplusplus(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) but i didn't really understand that

Comment: @Chris: The `string::find` method returns the position of the found character, or `std::string::npos` if not found.